# Getting dimensions of an Android device in dp

Tags: java, android, screen-size

I.e. the Samsung S6 Edge has the screen dimensions 1440x2560 pixels.

However, I need them in `dp` instead. How can I programatically get the dimensions (width and height) of an Android device in `dp`?

Answer (score 3):

You can get DisplayMetrics

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

and access `density` value:

> The logical density of the display. This is a scaling factor for the
>   Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP is one pixel on an
>   approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen),
>   providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi
>   screen this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be
>   .75; etc.
>
> This value does not exactly follow the real screen size (as given by
>   xdpi and ydpi, but rather is used to scale the size of the overall UI
>   in steps based on gross changes in the display dpi. For example, a
>   240x320 screen will have a density of 1 even if its width is 1.8",
>   1.3", etc. However, if the screen resolution is increased to 320x480 but the screen size remained 1.5"x2" then the density would be
>   increased (probably to 1.5).